# Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and let $0\leq b\leq\mu(A)$. Show there is measurable $B\subset A$ with $\mu(B)=b$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and let $0\leq b\leq\mu(A)$. Show there is measurable $B\subset  A$ with $\mu(B)=b$.

This is a qual problem. I tried approaching this with inner regularity. For all $\varepsilon>0$ there is some closed $F_{\epsilon}\subset A$ with $\mu(A\setminus F_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$. I want to somehow take a compliment and find a sequence of sets converging in measure to $B$ but I can't seem to do so. Perhaps letting $\varepsilon=\mu(A)-b$ (with the trivial case $\mu(A)=b$ dealt with separately) might prove useful?

I would like hints only please.

Comment: what is $\mu$, lebesgue measure ?

Comment: @Surb That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Define a function $ f : \mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty) $ by $ f(x) = \mu(A \cap [-x, x]) $. It is easy to check that $ f $ is continuous. Now, consider $ f(0) $ and $ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) $.

Comment: Cool, I think this works. $f(0)=0$, and the limit is $\mu(A)$ so by IVT we have that it hits every point between. Sweet!